# Подскажите как скрыть сайдбар на смартфоне

Tags: css

Всем привет.

Есть сайдбар который появляетсья и скрываетсья по клику.Проблема в том что в смартфонах он не скрываетсья .В смартфонах он показываетсья с права и не скрываетсья.Появляетсья горизонтальный скролл и если поскроллить вправо то сайдбар там будет.

Очень прошу помогите 3 дня не могу решить.

Также есть [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/YJBxbp)

Со смартфона можно посмотреть перейдя по [**ссылке**](https://duudexx8.github.io/QUIZ.github.io/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const label = document.querySelector(".label");
  const sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  const arrow = document.querySelector(".sidebar-arrow");
  const mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");
    label.onclick = () => {
        
        if(window.innerWidth >= 992){
          sidebar.classList.toggle("transform");
          arrow.classList.toggle("rotate");
          mainContent.classList.toggle("margin-left");
        } else {
          sidebar.classList.toggle("transform");
          arrow.classList.toggle("rotate");
        }
    }      
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  right: 0px;
  transition: transform .2s linear;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.sidebar .sidebar-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-content h4 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-content table {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-content table tr {
  background-color: #14161C;
}

.transform {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.sidebar.transform .label {
  background: transparent;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.label {
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: opacity .2s linear;
}
.label .pointer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  top: 50vh;
}
.label .pointer span {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  right: 25px;
  top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.label .pointer .sidebar-arrow {
  background: url(http://mapfestival.az/assets/img/slider-arrow-left.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform  0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-content">
            <h1 class="main-title">asdasdas <br> QasdasdZ</h1>

            <button id="start-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);">asdasdN</a></button>
            <div class="main-txt">
                <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, 
                    but the majority have suffered alteration in some form,
                    by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even 
                    slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem
                    Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing 
                    hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators
                    on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary,
                    making this the first true generator on the Internet. 
                    It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined 
                    with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate 
                    Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem
                    Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected
                    humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
            <div id="label" class="label">
                <div class="pointer">
                    <div class="sidebar-arrow"></div>
                    <span>LEADERBOARDS</span>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="sidebar-content">
                <h4>LEADERBOARDS</h4>
               <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: странное сочетание js и jquery .....используйте что то одно, так как jquery умеет тоже что и js

Comment: @НикитаФаст да неужели.Капитан очевидность

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, на мобилках есть проблема с контентом, выходящим за пределы экрана. Можно использовать "костыль": обернуть сайдбар в div, задать ему width: 100% и overflow-x: hidden

Comment: сделал всеравно не сработал =(

Comment: Сработал принимаю ответ спасибо.А почему это костыль?

Comment: Ну, потому что это лишний, в общем-то, div - он не несёт какого-то смысла для вёрстки кроме сокрытия сайдбара на мобилках. Просто я другого варианта не знаю и сам всегда делаю так :))

Comment: благодарью :) )